# Handling exceptions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions, ruby-on-rails-5, rollback

I am bit unclear about exception handling while using Active record transactions in rails. I have seen many of them using,

Method: 1

```
def update
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    begin
      # Some logic
    rescue StandardError => e
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end
```

and have seen the below logics in many of the places.

Method:2

```
def update
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
   if object.update(update_params)
     # success
   else
     # error handling
    end
  end

rescue => e
  # error handling
end
```

What I think is the second method itself is enough. I thought that, Transaction itself will rollback if anything unexpected happens or any logical error inside the transaction and we can catch them and do whatever we want. Is catching exception inside the transaction and **raising Rollback manually** needed anywhere?. What is the difference between both the methods and in which case?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually to rollback the transaction the code below should be good enough

```
def update

  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    foo.update(foo_update_params)
  end

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  # Handle your exception here
end
```

Have a look [here](https://medium.com/@kristenrogers.kr75/rails-transactions-the-complete-guide-7b5c00c604fc) for a better explanation.